# Handle a Form Controls Events from a Class

Tags: vb.net, events, event-handling

The next code works for my, but I d'ont know if it's the best way to do it. 
Of this way I need to write: _Button1 = Button1 and _MyVar = MyVar
This way of doing it seems repetitive and long when the parameters
passed to the Class Constructor are many more.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim myVar As String = "My children"
        Dim NewClass1 As New Class1(Button1, myVar)
        '... do more ...
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Class1
    Private WithEvents _Button1 As Button
    Private _MyVar As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal Button1 As Button, ByVal MyVar As String)
        _Button1 = Button1
        _MyVar = MyVar
    '... do more ...
    End Sub

    Private Sub _Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles _Button1.Click
        MsgBox("Button1 clicked and I love: " & _MyVar)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Don't handle the click event before you even have an actual button. Use `AddHandler` in the constructor instead.

Answer (score 0):

> _Button1 = Button1 and _MyVar = MyVar This way of doing it seems repetitive and long when the parameters passed to the Class Constructor are many more.

This is actually dependency injection and is usually a good thing. If you end up with too many constructor parameters then it should be a clue that your class is doing too many things and is in violation of [SOLID](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SOLID.aspx) principles.

However, your `Class1` should not have dependencies on `Form1`, it should be the other way around. Your code could much more simply be:

```
Public Class Class1
    Friend Sub DoSomething(ByVal MyVar As String)
        MsgBox(MyVar)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form1
    Public Property class1() As Class1

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.class1 = New Class1()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        class1.DoSomething("blah, blah")
    End Sub
End Class
```

While I am not demonstrating dependency injection here (for simplicity), you can see `Class1` only knows that it can do some work, it doesn't know about the Form at all.

You could subscribe to the button click event in `Class1` instead of passing the button into it. It would be cleaner, but still bad design.